# Ejercicio con arreglo (array), C++, Programa que pide estaturas y las imprime

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, float

Tengo el código de un programa que solicita la estatura, sin embargo no puedo hacer que se muestren las características del programa, anexo como se debería ver en contraste con el código, si me pudieran ayudar lo apreciaría mucho.

**COMO DEBERÍA MOSTRARSE AL EJECUTARSE:**

> ```
> Capture estatura: 1.56
> Capture estatura: 1.70
> Capture estatura: 1.40
> Capture estatura: 1.55
> Capture estatura: 1.85
> Capture estatura: 1.95
> Capture estatura: 1.50
> Capture estatura: 1.41
> Capture estatura: 1.60
> Capture estatura: 1.61
>
> LOS DATOS CAPTURADOS SON:
> 1.56 ,1.70, 1.40, 1.55, 1.85, 1.95, 1.50, 1.41, 1.60, 1.61
> ESTATURA MÁXIMA: 1.95           
> PROMEDIO DE ESTATURAS: 1.61
> ```

**CÓDIGO**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float estatura[10];
    int prom,suma=0;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Capture estatura:";
            cin>>estatura[i];

        }
cout<<"LOS DATOS CAPTURADOS SON:"<<endl;    
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<estatura[i]<<endl;
            suma=suma+estatura[i];
        }   
prom=suma/10;
cout<<"El promedio de calificaciones es:"<<prom;        
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Has etiquetado tu pregunta como [tag:c++] pero la mayoría de cabeceras que usas son de [tag:c] y ni siquiera necesitas usarlas. Quita `<conio.h>`, `<stdio.h>` y `<stdlib.h>`, ni las usas ni las necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo no estas seteando la estatura máxima, tampoco estas asignandola ni mostrandola, en la iteración de solicitud de estatura estas terminando con un salto de linea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float estatura[10],prom,suma=0.0,max=-99.99;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Capture estatura:";
            cin>>estatura[i];

        }
cout<<"LOS DATOS CAPTURADOS SON:"<<endl;    
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(i <9){
                cout<<estatura[i]<<",";
            }else{
                cout<<estatura[i];

            }
            suma+=estatura[i];
            if(estatura[i]>max){
                max = estatura[i];
            }
        }   
        cout<<endl;
prom=suma/10;
cout<<"Estatura maxima: "<<max<<endl;
cout<<"El promedio de estatura es:"<<prom<<endl;        
}
```